# critical magnetic field superconductivity suppression in SQUIDs

Tags: magnetic-fields, superconductivity

Superconducting quantum interference devices are used as very sensitive magnetometers. However, on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer#SQUID_.28Superconducting_quantum_interference_device.29) page, it claims that SQUIDS can be used to measure fields up to 7T. How can a device that relies on superconductivity be used to measure such a high field? Or is it simply a matter of finding a superconducting material that can remain superconducting up to the level that is needed?

Comment: the critical field of [some materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_diboride) is higher than $70\ \mathrm{T}$. $7\ \mathrm{T}$ is a really mild number.